# Get statement not adding to database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

i'm trying to use a get statement in a variable to add data to a data base, when i try to do this nothing is added under folder however if i add plain text it is added. (i'm trying to add to the folder section)
My entire html document is provided below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="newfile.css">
    <title>Folder</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    include_once 'dbh.php';
echo $_GET["data"];
   if(isset($_GET["data"])) {
    $location = $_GET["data"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE folder LIKE '%$location%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
    if($queryResult > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo $row['content'];
        }
    } else {
            echo "There are no results matching your search!";
    }
    }
?>
<?php

$uploadpath = 'postimages/';      // directory to store the uploaded files
$max_size = 3116718;          // maximum file size, in KiloBytes
$alwidth = 100000;            // maximum allowed width, in pixeli
$alheight = 100000;           // maximum allowed height, in pixeli
$allowtype = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'jpe', 'png', 'docx', 'psd', 'pdf', 'pptx', 'html', 'php', 'css', 'js', 'mp4', 'mp3');        // allowed extensions

if(isset($_FILES['fileup'])) {
  $uploadpath = $uploadpath . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);
  $name = basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']);
  $type = end(explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fileup']['name'])));
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name']);     // gets image width and height
  $err = '';

  // Checks if the file has allowed type, size, width and height (for images)
  if(!in_array($type, $allowtype)) $err .= 'The file <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['name']. '</b> not has the allowed extension type.';
  if($_FILES['fileup']['size'] > $max_size*900000) $err .= '<br/>Maximum file size must be: '. $max_size. ' KB';
  if(isset($width) && isset($height) && ($width >= $alwidth || $height >= $alheight)) $err .= '<br/>The maximum Width x Height must be: '. $alwidth. ' x 
  '. $alheight;

  // If no errors, upload the image, else, output the errors
  if($err == '') {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) { 
        $content =  $name;
        $realfiledest = $uploadpath;
        $username = 'user';
        $folder = $_GET['data'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (content, img, folder, date) VALUES ('$content', '$realfiledest',  '$folder', NOW());";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($result !== false) {
            header("Location: fold.php?data=Math");    

        }else{
            echo "fail";
        }

    }
    else echo '<b>Unable to upload the file.</b>';
  }
  else echo $err;
}

?> 
<div class="upform">
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <div class="image-upload">
                <label for="file-input">
                    <img src="add-file.png" />
                </label>
                <input id="file-input" type="file" name="fileup"/>            
                
            </div>       
            <input class="noshow" type="text" id="wow" placeholder="<?php echo $_GET['data']; ?>" name='name'>          
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name='submit'  value="U P L O A D" /> 
        </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:file').change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $("#submit").show();
                    // or, as has been pointed out elsewhere:
                    // $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
                } 
            }
            )     
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

url= http://localhost/smart%20assist/fold.php?data=Math

Any help would be awesome, Thanks

Comment: Please upload your full code with HTML form?

Comment: Done, thanks so much

Comment: This is single page code or multiple page code.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you doing file uploading you are using post method in your form with multi-part, right.

now, if you want to send something with your url as query params, then you have to use `$_REQUEST`. In your case,

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath)) { 
        $content =  $name;
        $realfiledest = $uploadpath;
        $username = 'user';
        $folder = $_REQUEST['data'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (content, img, folder, date) VALUES ('$content', '$realfiledest',  '$folder', NOW());";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

If you facing the same problem, I need to check your HTML form, to help you in a better way.

Comment: @AnthonyWaymouth please vote as answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you made below mistakes.

1. You are not posting "data" field value in your HTML.
2. You must put the name field for get data.
3. You are posting the form for using post method. So you should be used `$_POST[]` or `$_REQUEST[]`.

please verify your HTML.